# Angular ngModel not select with ngFor [HTML SELECT INPUT]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7iiaw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

The select input is "" instead 1

HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]="subcategoria.categoria" class="input-default" name="status_categoria" id="status_categoria">
  <option *ngFor="let categoria of categorias" value="{{categoria.id}}">{{categoria.nome}}</option>
</select>
```

Typescript

```
subcategoria: Array<any> = [{
    categoria:1
  }];
  categorias: Array<any> = [{id:1,nome:"one"},{id:2,nome:"two"}];
```

Comment: There is a problem in your code. `subcategoria` is an array and `subcategoria.categoria` does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subcategoria` is an Array, I think you want to access `subcategoria[0].categoria`. Or you need to change the value of `subcategoria` to

```
subcategoria = {
    categoria:1
};
```

[This is the working fix](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lh2rxm)

Answer (score 1):

In this,    `[(ngModel)]="subcategoria.categoria"`

```
subcategoria is an array and not an object
```

so use `[(ngModel)]="subcategoria[0].categoria"` for the default value

Answer (score 1):

You are using array as `ngModel`, so you have to change the `ngModel` as below,

```
[(ngModel)]="subcategoria[0].categoria"
```

Since `categoria` is the `0th` index of the `subcategoria` array you have to change the `ngModel` to bind the value

Answer (score 1):

```
subcategeria is an array so you should address it like this [(ngModel)]=subcategeria[0].categeria
```

Or another solution is to change the subcategeria Array to an Object:

```
subcategoria = {
   categeria:1
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you need either change `subcategoria` from array to object or access to the object using `arr[index]`